# convert SQL table to java bean class

Tags: java, sql, javabeans

I'm working in web application using a huge number of SQL tables. I need to create for each table a java bean class. I'm searching for a tool that can convert  SQL table to a java bean class. It will help to save time.

Here is an example:

studentTable (studentId, firstname, lastname, yearLevel)

```
-->

public class Student {
    @Id
    @Column
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int studentId;
    @Column
    private String firstname;
    @Column
    private String lastname;
    @Column
    private int yearLevel;

    public Student(){}
    public Student(int studentId, String firstname, String lastname,
            int yearLevel) {
        super();
        this.studentId = studentId;
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.yearLevel = yearLevel;
    }
    public int getStudentId() {
        return studentId;
    }
    public void setStudentId(int studentId) {
        this.studentId = studentId;
    }
    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }
    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }
    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }
    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }
    public int getYearLevel() {
        return yearLevel;
    }
    public void setYearLevel(int yearLevel) {
        this.yearLevel = yearLevel;
    }
}
```

Do you have any idea about such tool.

Comment: You could do a mysqldump and run a script on this file to create a java file.

Comment: @Bikiew thnx for your answer. I did a mysqldump and i got a .sql file. Can you please explain to me now how to run a script on this file to create the java bean ?

Comment: Check out Seam. It's clunky, but works superbly,including all relationships

Comment: I haven't tried these but it seems to be close to what you want. http://sql2java.sourceforge.net/ http://sourceforge.net/projects/middlegen/ http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/tools.html

Comment: this online tool generate class from database table based on the CREATE TABLE script, from MS-SQL, ORACLE and MYSQL databases to class in JAVA and other programming languages: https://codverter.com/src/sqltoclass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Hibernate.

It allows you to generate model-classes for your database tables.

The "function" is called: `Hibernate mapping files and POJO'S from database`, also use `Hibernate Reverse Engineering Wizard`.

I use Netbeans and Hibernate to generate all these models.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I found the solution thanks to hibernate eclipse plugin. It allows java bean classes and hibernate config files generation

Comment: I found the solution thanks to these two links : 

 http://omtlab.com/java-hibernate-reverse-engineering-eclipse-tutorial/

 http://www.wikihow.com/Generate-Hibernate-Pojo-Classes-from-DB-Tables

enjoy !

Comment: some details about HOW you use Netbeans or even a link to a good netbeans walk through you would recommend would make this a vote up answer...

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse has such functionality, but I'm not sure that it works correctly for all cases and that it properly handles relations between tables. In any case take a look at this [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/cioroianu-eclipse-jpa-084626.html)(**Creating and Modifying Entities** section), it might help.