# Generate "very" basic Bean from a database table?

Tags: java, database, javabeans

I would like to generate a very simple and basic Bean from a given table.
I want it to be as simple as possible.

Take this example:
Suppose you have the following table:

```
UsersTable {
   idUser: integer (PK),
   Login: varchar(100),
   Password: varchar(100),
   CreationDate: datetime
}
```

I want to generate the following class from this table:

```
public class Users {
     private Integer idUser;
     private String Login;
     private String Password;
     private Date CreationDate;

     /*
        With somme getters and setters if possible, 
        else make the properties public instead of private) 
     */
}
```

Creating POJO from Database as it is offered by Netbeans generate lot of "unwanted" things (@annotation, named queries, imports, etc.).

Thank you.

Comment: :) it is not practical when your database contains hundred of tables.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16524481/4028085

Comment: If you can't find anything that meets your needs you could write a custom program that does it for u...

Comment: Yes! It is possible - metadata... I must be sure that there no tools that can do this for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest entity I could think of.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "UsersTable")
public class Users{

    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="idUser")
    protected Integer idUser;

    @Column(name = "Login")
    public String login;

    @Column(name = "Password")
    public String password;

    @Column(name = "CreationDate")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date creationDate;


    /* Getters and Setters */
}
```

Comment: I already mentioned that I do not want the @annotation nor any dependency to an external library. Is there any thing simpler ? :)

Comment: Well, this question is tagged as JPA, so that is why I went as an entity. The only thing simpler is what you have listed in your question. Can you elaborate on what exactly you want to do with this POJO that the POJO you have listed cant do?